# body_class filter - Is there a better way to write this code?

Tags: php, filters, body-class

I would like to add a body class depending on what sidebars are active, and a body class if my before-header widget area is active. I have got it to work, but I would just like to know if there is a better way to write it as my `before header widget area function` for some reason needs to be above my `sidebar function`, otherwise my `sidebar function` doesn't work if my `before header widget area function` is active. So I'm sure there is some bad practice code in there somewhere.

Here is the working one:

```
// add body class if before-header-widget is active
add_filter( 'body_class', 'body_class_before_header' );
function body_class_before_header( $classes ) {

    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'before-header-widget-area' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'before-header';
        return $classes;
    } 
}


// add body classes for sidebars
add_filter( 'body_class', 'body_class_layouts' );
function body_class_layouts( $classes ) {

    // add body class if both sidebars are active
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-right' ) && is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-left' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'sidebar-content-sidebar';
        return $classes;
    }

    // add body class for if right sidebar is active
    elseif ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-right' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'content-sidebar';
        return $classes;
    }

    // add body class for if left sidebar is active
    elseif ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-left' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'sidebar-content';
        return $classes;
    }

    // add body class if no sidebars are active
    else {
        $classes[] = 'full-width-content';
        return $classes;
    }
}
```

But if I simply swap the functions the other way:

```
 // add body classes for Sidebars
    add_filter( 'body_class', 'body_class_layouts' );
    function body_class_layouts( $classes ) {

        // add body class if both sidebars are active
        if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-right' ) && is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-left' ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'sidebar-content-sidebar';
            return $classes;
        }

        // add body class for if right sidebar is active
        elseif ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-right' ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'content-sidebar';
            return $classes;
        }

        // add body class for if left sidebar is active
        elseif ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-left' ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'sidebar-content';
            return $classes;
        }

        // add body class if no sidebars are active
        else {
            $classes[] = 'full-width-content';
            return $classes;
        }
    }

    // add body class if before-header-widget is active
    add_filter( 'body_class', 'body_class_before_header' );
    function body_class_before_header( $classes ) {

        if ( is_active_sidebar( 'before-header-widget-area' ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'before-header';
            return $classes;
        } 
    }
```

None of my active layout sidebar classes will go into the body tag if the `before-header-widget` is active. I don't want my `sidebars function` to have anything to do with my `before-header-widget` function. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that there is a much smarter way to write this code in a procedural style, so basically your code looks okay.

But there's a logic error in your `body_class_before_header()` function which might cause the issue: If the conditional block is not executed, the function will return `NULL` but as it is a callback on a *filter* it should always return at least the unfiltered parameter value:

```
// add body class if before-header-widget is active
add_filter( 'body_class', 'body_class_before_header' );
function body_class_before_header( $classes ) {

    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'before-header-widget-area' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'before-header';
        //don't return here (only)
    }

    //return $classes anyway
    return $classes;
}
```

There's one more small syntax improvement, maybe.

```
function body_class_layouts( $classes ) {

    // add body class if both sidebars are active
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-right' ) && is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-left' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'sidebar-content-sidebar';
    }

    // add body class for if right sidebar is active
    elseif ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-right' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'content-sidebar';
    }

    // add body class for if left sidebar is active
    elseif ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-left' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'sidebar-content';
    }

    // add body class if no sidebars are active
    else {
        $classes[] = 'full-width-content';
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

I removed all the `return` statements from the conditional blocks and moved it to the end of the function. This might help to avoid a `NULL` return under certain conditions.

Comment: I would still just add everything in **one** function, not two

Comment: @PieterGoosen depends on the context for me.

Comment: You're right David. That fixed it. Thanks for your help :)